# add redux persist in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, persistence, redux-toolkit

I am using next.js with typescript and node.js. I am using redux toolkit for global store. I added Redux Persist to store data even if I refresh the site. It is working fine on localhost, but after I deploy it to a live server, the site stops working. There are no errors displayed. I believe it may not be working due to my use of Next.js."

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'

// import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"; // or choose another storage option

// Import your reducers
import productReducer from "@/features/product/productSlice";
import cartReducer from "../features/cart/cartSlice";
import orderSlice from "@/components/Checkout/orderSlice";
import userReducer from "../../src/features/User/userSlice";
import recentlyClickedReducer from "@/features/product/recentlyClickedSlice";
import createWebStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage";

const createNoopStorage = () => {
  return {
    getItem(_key:any) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    },
    setItem(_key:any, value:any) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    },
    removeItem(_key:any) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
  };
};

const storage = typeof window !== "undefined" ? createWebStorage("local") : createNoopStorage();

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};

const persistedProductReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, productReducer);
const persistedCartReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, cartReducer);
const persistedOrderReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, orderSlice);
const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);
const persistedRecentlyClickedReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  recentlyClickedReducer
);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    product: persistedProductReducer,
    cart: persistedCartReducer,
    order: persistedOrderReducer,
    user: persistedUserReducer,
    recentlyClicked: persistedRecentlyClickedReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),

});


export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

this is my store.tsx file.

```
import Layout from "@/components/Layout/Layout";
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { store } from "../redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";



export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return (
    
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

this is my _app.tsx

If you know another way to store data without using persist, please suggest that as well

Comment: import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
This is also not working, which is why I use createWebStorage